# Spherical Cow Calculus 1

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Can someone please help me with the 3 calculus one word problems below, I've done all three of them several times but can never seem to arrive at the correct answer. This is greatly frustrating because these questions seem simple enough but I've wasted so much time on them. Thank you.

1)Fred the spherical cow is happily grazing on cubical grass pellets. He grows in volume at a rate of 20 cubic feet per day.

When Fred's radius is 14 feet, at what rate is his surface area growing?

2) Fred the spherical cow is happily grazing on cubical grass pellets. He grows in volume at a rate of 8 cubic feet per day.

When Fred's radius is 11 feet, at what rate is his surface area growing?

3) Fred the spherical cow is happily grazing on cubical grass pellets. He grows in volume at a rate of 11 cubic feet per day.

When Fred's radius is 6 feet, at what rate is his surface area growing?

Comment: Show us what you tried on each so that we can help you figure it out.

Comment: The purpose of this forum is not to have other people do your homework. You need to try yourself. If you get stuck you should share what you have tried, what your thoughts on the problem is etc. If you don't even try to solve your homework yourself there is little point in helping you.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Math.SE.  This question as it currently stands is at risk of being closed largely because it's actually three questions and there isn't much context here.  To remedy this I would suggest in general that you break these into three separate questions, but in this case I recommend asking only one of them since they're all the same but with different numbers.  Then try the other two on your own.  Also, you need to give us details about your failed attempts so that we can more efficiently and accurately help you.

Comment: Ok. Here is what I did for the first one. I applied the same chain rule reasoning to the other two as they are literally the same problem with different numbers but this did not work.

Comment: 1) His rate of change of Volume , dV/dt = 20 (cubic feet per day) and we are asked to find the rate of change of area dA/dt. 
By the Chain Rule, (dV/dt) = (dV/dr) x (dr/dt) . . . and dV/dr = d(⁴/₃ π r³)/dr = 4πr² 
So, 20 = 4πr² x (dr/dt) : (dr/dt) = 20 / 4πr² = 5 / πr². 
Now, (dA/dt) = (dA/dr) x (dr/dt) . . . and dA/dr = d(4πr²)/dr = 8πr 
So, dA/dt = 8πr x 5 / πr² = 40/r 
When r =14 then dA/dt = 40/14 = 2.857 sq ft per day.

Comment: Thanks for the help @MSEoris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its volume is given by
$$V=\frac{4\pi r^3}{3}$$
Differentiate with respect to $r$:
$$\frac{dV}{dr}=4\pi r^2$$
By the chain rule you have
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{dV}{dr}\frac{dr}{dt}=4\pi r^2\frac{dr}{dt}=20$$
Solve for $\frac{dr}{dt}$:
$$\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{20}{4\pi r^2}=\frac{5}{\pi r^2}$$

Its surface area is given by
$$A=4\pi r^2$$
Differentiate with respect to $r$:
$$\frac{dA}{dr}=8\pi r$$
Now use chain rule to get the rate at which the area changes with respect to time:
$$\frac{dA}{dt}=\frac{dA}{dr}\frac{dr}{dt}=8\pi r\frac{dr}{dt}=8\pi r\cdot\frac{5}{\pi r^2}=\frac{40}{r}.$$

Comment: This was the same thing I did. Comically, I found out that the software I was using required answers to be inputted in fractions and not decimals. Thank you though.